# Display a user's responses to a webform in the webform but uneditable

Tags: 8, webforms

Use-case: The user completes the webform but is still able to view it, in the webform structure, but uneditable. They finished it, they can't change it.

I know we can add a "lock" to a completed webform submission using an action handler, but I've played around with various options and I just can't see any  way to do this.

Is it a matter of creating a wrapper theme, maybe, that sets every element to readonly?